# Black Screen after login with multiple montitors connected through docking station

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I suddenly get black screen after I log in when I have two monitors connected through docking station.

When I first log in and then connect the monitors all is well untill I try to change scaling factor (which I have to because it's it's too large on the connected monitors otherwise) and click on "Apply" in the Screen settings. Then all three  screens go black and don't come alive again.

Strangely, when I connect the monitors directly to the pc it works. But I experience the same behavior with two identical docking stations. Windows (dual boot) has no such problems. Yesterday all worked fine. What to do?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

PC: Lenovo T470p, GeForce 940MX

Docking: Ultra Dock Type 40A2

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem. It appears that the upgrade changes the sync-rate to 120Hz.  I could fix the problem by restoring the sync-rate to 60Hz for the primary screen in the "Display" setting with no docking station attached. Then re-attach the docking station.